# How do I count between same shape ndarrays?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

In the calculation of 0-1 image 2d-entropy, I need to get neighbor grayscale probability distribution:

```
img=np.random.randint(0,2,(64,64))

avg=avgpool2d(img,kernel_size=3,padding=1).numpy() * 9

avg = avg.astype(np.int32)

distribution=np.zeros((2,9))

for i,j in zip(img.flat,avg.flat):

    distribution[i,j]+=1
```

I want to avoid loop using a numpy way, but fancy indexing doesn't seem to work here:

```
a=np.zeros((3,))

b=np.array([1,0,0])

a[b]+=1 # a=[1,1,0] not [2,1,0]
```

so

```
img=np.random.randint(0,2,(64,64))

avg=avgpool2d(img,kernel_size=3,padding=1).numpy() * 9

avg = avg.astype(np.int32)

distribution=np.zeros((2,9))

distribution[img,avg]+=1
```

gives wrong result

Is there an elegant way to count between two(or more) arrays?

More broadly, how do I count the number of occurrences N-tuple (a1,...,an) where a1,...,an have same indexes idx in different array X1,..,Xn: ai = Xi[idx]?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
a=np.zeros((3,))
b=np.array([1,0,0])

idx, cnt = np.unique(b, return_counts=True)
a[idx] += cnt
```

Or [`numpy.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) (in place):

```
np.add.at(a, b, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([2., 1., 0.])
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a multi-dimension index here so numpy.unique does not work, but  numpy.add.at works well: `np.add.at(distribution,(img,avg),1)`.  What if elements in img or avg are so huge that bucket count is no longer possible? In other words, how do I count the number of occurrences N-tuple `(a1,...,an)` where `a1,...,an` have same indexes `idx` in different array `X1,..,Xn`: `ai = Xi[idx]`?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? You current one is large and relies on unspecified libraries (I guess pytorch), just give a defined (and meaningful) example and the matching output.

Comment: Of course yes, AvgPool is indeed a Pytorch class but let's ignore that. In a 2d case, suppose `a=np.array([2 ** 31, 0, 0])`,`b=np.array([1, 3, 3])` 
so `count=np.array([1,2])` and `element=np.array([[2**31,1],[0,3]])` which count[i] indicate the number of occurrences of element[i,...] How do i design `count_fun(a,b) -> (count, element)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use numpy.unique

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([1,       0, 0, 1,])
b = np.array([2 ** 10, 0, 0, 0,])


def count_fun(*args):
    co = np.stack(args,axis=-1)
    print('co\n',co)
    element, count = np.unique(co, return_counts=True, axis=0)
    print('element\n',element)
    print('count\n',count)
    return element, count

count_fun(a,b)
```

outs:

```
co
 [[   1 1024]
 [   0    0]
 [   0    0]
 [   1    0]]
element
 [[   0    0]
 [   1    0]
 [   1 1024]]
count
 [2 1 1]
```